# Excel VBA Automatic creation/updating a drop-down list from files/images in a folder

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, directory, automatic-updates

I am looking to merge my scripts to work togheter, my drop-down list (ComboBox) script, to my current script that loads pictures/images into the heading of my Excel sheet.

My script for loading the images looks like this (and works):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myPict As Picture
Dim PictureLoc As String

If Target.Address = Range("A2").Address Then

ActiveSheet.Pictures.Delete

PictureLoc = "K:\Images" & Range("A2").Value & ".png"

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .CenterHeaderPicture.Filename = PictureLoc
    .CenterHeaderPicture.Height = 25
    '.CenterHeaderPicture.Width = 100
    .CenterHeader = "&G"
End With

End If

End Sub
```

My script that updates the ComboBox with the newest pictures from my folder (and this works also):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Filename = Dir("K:\Images\", vbNormal)

ComboBox1.Clear

Do While Len(Filename) > 0

ComboBox1.AddItem Filename

Filename = Dir()
Loop


End Sub
```

My problem is getting my first script (loading images into heading) to run with the value/name chosen in the ComboBox. It works perfect for a normal validationg list in Cell A2, but I can't get it to fetch the value in the ComboBox instead of A2. I have tried changing the first part of the script to the following, but it will not fetch the value:

```
Dim PictureLoc As String

'If Target.Address = Range("A2").Address Then
If Target.Address = ComboBox1.Address Then

ActiveSheet.Pictures.Delete

'PictureLoc = "K:\Images\" & Range("A2").Value & ".jpg"
PictureLoc = "K:\Images\" & ComboBox1.Value '& ".jpg"

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .CenterHeaderPicture.Filename = PictureLoc
    .CenterHeaderPicture.Height = 25
    '.CenterHeaderPicture.Width = 100
    .CenterHeader = "&G"
End With

End If

End Sub
```

Any suggestions?